# Why is this Binning by Median code wrong?

Tags: r, data-mining, dataset, statistics

I was working on Binning by Mean, Median and Boundary in R.

```
# R CODE
a=c(20.5, 52.5, 62.6, 72.4, 104.8, 63.9, 35.3, 83.9, 37.4, 71.6, 74.6, 44.5, 66.6, 56.1, 45.3, 37.2)
a=sort(a)
binsize=4
median(a[1:4])
# BINS ARE
for(i in 1:length(a))
{
  if(i%%binsize==0)
  {
    print("HI")
    print(a[i-3])
    print(a[i-2])
    print(a[i-1])
    print(a[i])
  }
}

# BINNING BY MEAN
sum=0
for(i in 1:length(a))
{
  sum=sum+a[i]
    if(i%%binsize==0){
      avg=sum/binsize
      sum=0
      print(rep.int(avg,binsize))
    }
}

# BINNING BY MEDIAN
i=1
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  if(i%%binsize==0)
  {
    print(rep.int(median(a[i-3:i]),binsize))
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why binning by median is giving me wrong output.
The `median(a[i-3:i])` for 1st bin returns a value which is not same as `median(a[1:4])` for 1st bin. Why?

Comment: Instead of your loop-and-test `for(i in 1:length(a)){ if(i%%binsize==0) {...}}`, just use `seq(...by)` argument: `for(i in seq(binsize, length(a), by=binsize)) { ... }`

Comment: This is a very-well-known R gotcha and should have a canonical question over on SO, but it doesn't. I created [Canonical question for R gotcha: colon operator takes higher precedence than arithmetic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338980/canonical-question-for-r-gotcha-colon-operator-takes-higher-precedence-than-ari)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the **well-known R gotcha that the `:` (colon operator, which calls `seq()`) takes higher precedence than arithmetic**. Always parenthesize arguments to `:` if they involve arithmetic or are expressions: `a[(i-3):i]`

Your code `a[i-3:i]` doesn't do what you want it to do `a[(i-3):i]`, it does `a[i - (3:i)])`. So the medians you are printing are for these slices:

```
4-3:1 # i.e. 1:3
8-3:1 # i.e. 5:7
12-3:1 # i.e. 9:11
16-4:1 # i.e. 13:15
```

PS some coding-style tips

- You don't need to iterate over all possible values of i and check them modulo binsize, just do:

  `for(i in seq(binsize, length(a), by=binsize)) { ... }`

so in your median case:

```
for(i in seq(binsize, length(a), by=binsize)) {
  print(rep.int(median(a[(i-3):i]),binsize))
}
[1] 36.25 36.25 36.25 36.25
[1] 48.9 48.9 48.9 48.9
[1] 65.25 65.25 65.25 65.25
[1] 79.25 79.25 79.25 79.25
```

- But in fact you can replace even that with:

  `split(a, ceiling(seq_along(a)/binsize))`

  as per the ["Split a vector into chunks in R"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318333/split-a-vector-into-chunks-in-r)

  To make it even clearer, you could define a helper function `chunk <- function(x, binsize) { split(x, ceiling(seq_along(x)/binsize)) }`
- Then you can replace the for-loop with sapply:

.

```
sapply(split(a, ceiling(seq_along(a)/binsize)), mean)
sapply(chunk(a,binsize), mean)
     1      2      3      4 
32.600 49.600 66.175 83.925

sapply(split(a, ceiling(seq_along(a)/binsize)), median)
sapply(chunk(a,binsize), median)
    1     2     3     4 
36.25 48.90 65.25 79.25
```

Much cleaner, easier to read, and prevents errors, right?

- The generalization of the colon operator is the [`seq()` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html), give it a read, it's pretty useful.

Comment: Could you just tell me how to go for Binning by bin boundaries,
a pseudocode or a snippet would make it more helpful for me

Comment: @SharatAAinapur: added the line "so in your median case". You just needed to parenthesize your index expressions `a[(i-3):i` like it said in the first sentence.